# How to get background image in opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I need to get the background removing foreground from images of video[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jW0J.jpg).

- I need to remove the hand, pen and shadow.
- I need to get the line image only.

But I don't know how. Only I can find how to subtract background image.

I tried to subtract from the original image to the foreground image using this code to get foreground.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=50, detectShadows=True)
```

If there is any way to get only the line image?

Comment: My question can't solve with that answer. I need to get the line image. but with that answer I still have foreground image too. I edit my question more detail to show it's different question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do that using Running Average
we can do that using open-cv cv.accumulateWeighted() function, it may not extract the background as it supposed to be it kinda does the job fine.
here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

c = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_,f = c.read()

avg1 = np.float32(f)
avg2 = np.float32(f)

while(1):
    _,f = c.read()

    cv2.accumulateWeighted(f,avg1,0.1)
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(f,avg2,0.01)

    res1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg1)
    res2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg2)

    cv2.imshow('img',f)
    cv2.imshow('avg1',res1)
    cv2.imshow('avg2',res2)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20)

    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
c.release()
```

[image]
[image]

For further details, you can check the source [here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very interesting way. But when I tried to do with my mp4 file, it didn't work well. I need to get only line image but still I have blurred hand image. I can't remove the hand image. TT

Comment: @HaYoungKim Thanks a the interesting question. May be a little bit late, but have you found a way to get the background from the images ?